# discrete Grothendieck construction

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, grothendieck-construction

In "BASIC CONCEPTS OF ENRICHED CATEGORY THEORY", (version Reprints in Theory and Applications of Categories, No. 10, 2005), chapter 4.7 p.75-76, Kelly introduces the "discrete Grothendieck construction" in the case V=Set, and says that he'll treat the cases V=Gpd and V=Cat in an article
"[46] G.M. Kelly, Categories with structure – biadjoints for algebraic functors, to appear."

I can't find this article under that name, does anyone have a reference for this?

Thanks!

Comment: A relevant paper is "Two-dimensional monad theory" by Blackwell, Kelly and Power.  Theorem 5.12 of that paper certainly gives an important result on biadjoints for algebraic functors.

Comment: The paper in question never appeared; see [list of category theory papers that never appeared](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/list+of+category+theory+papers+that+never+appeared).

Answer (score 3):

The name of that article changed (a lot, it seems): the information you seek is in the paper *Doctrinal Adjunction* by Kelly. It lies on page 257 of the collection

> **Category Seminar**, Number 420 of *Lecture Notes in Mathematics*, Springer-Verlag (1974).

You can at least sample the first few pages of the article [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0063105).

Comment: This is a different paper: both "Categories with structure – biadjoints for algebraic functors" and "Doctrinal adjunction" are referenced separately in *Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory*.